# Java Iterator Class - Cannot resolve symbol "E"

Tags: java, oop, collections, iterator

I am learning about the implementation of the Iterator Class by programming a binary tree which uses this class as an iterator for `java.util.AbstractCollections` . However, I am not sure how I should use the `<E>` in the class declaration. I am kinda familiar with the `<T>` symbol, but, unfortunatly, I am unable to find a good explanation on how to use it and why it's there. I have already been to the Java 8 documentation.

When I do try to compile it, the compiler yields 
`Cannot resolve symbol "E"`

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<T>` `<E>` it is all the same. `<T>` is probably 'type', `<E>` probably 'element'. The name of the symbol doesn't matter. A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.

Comment: `E` is just like `T`, a reprentation of type

Comment: Type parameter names are like argument names - not important to code outside whatever declares the name. They're not like class names or method names.

Comment: Take a look at [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mix type declaration and type use :

```
public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<E> {...}      
                            ^--- type declaration  ^--- type use
```

Similarly this is also a type declaration and a type use :

```
public <T> T (T object){
        ^  ^--^-- type uses
        |-- type declaration
}
```

Your issue is that the compiler accepts `T` as a type can be declared with any valid identifier and `T` does. But it doesn't accept `E` as you cannot use a type that doesn't exit.

You may declare a type and by using another but it makes no sense :

```
public class BSTreeIterator<E> implements Iterator<String> {...}
```

Generally as you want that a class implements a generic interface while being itself a generic class you "forward" the generic type in the class to keep it the same in both such as :

```
public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the generic type doesn't matter, but you must help the compiiler by indicating how to relate the type of the implemented interface to the class. Either choose `E` or `T`. As you seem to have a preference for `T` you should use it as `BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>`, so the compiler knows that the `T` generic is for both the same and substitutable.

```
public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
      return null;
  }
```

The compiler error you got was because you return `E` in the `next()` method, but you did not define a `E` generic on the `BSTreeIterator` class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate the same type of elements as the type given to `BSTreeIterator`, so change

```
public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<E> {
```

to

```
public class BSTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing up Java generic type identifiers.

First try implementing the class.

```
public class BSTreeIterator implements Iterator<String>
```

Once you figure out how to do that,
add the generic operator to the BSTreeIterator.
That class will look something like this:

```
public class BSTreeIterator<ElementType> implements Iterator<ElementType>
```

It is a common,
lazy practice to use a one character value for the generics type name
(E in your example).
I recommend against lazy development practices.

Comment: "It is a common, lazy practice to use a one character value for the generics type name". I disagree with this. You could just as easily argue that it's lazy practice to use `i` rather than `theNumberOfTimesThatWeHavePresentlyBeenAroundThisParticularForLoop`. Most of the time, "some random type" is all we know about a generic type parameter. Using `T` to mean 'type' is part of idiomatic Java.

Comment: A competent developer would consider `index` as a name of a simple index.  A lazy (incompetent IMHO) would use `i`.  Using `T` to mean "type" is idiotomatic to java.  `Type` is both meaningful and reasonable.

Comment: `ElementType` doesn't really give you more information than `T` - maybe even less because single letters are idiomatic and easily identifiable as generics. If I see `ElementType` I would think it's another proper type, not a generic type. By the way there already is `java.lang.annotation.ElementType` and `java.lang.reflect.Type` which would make it even more confusing.

Comment: "idiotomatic" nice... Personally, when I see something like `ElementType` used in generics, I assume it's a concrete class. I have to scan elsewhere on the method (or possibly all the way to the top of the class) to see whether it was defined as a type. That's annoying and probably error prone. If I see a single character identifier such as `T`, I can be certain that it is a generic type parameter just by looking at it (not because it's *impossible* to have a class called `T` but because anyone who checked in such a thing would get a slap).

Comment: Little did Oracle and OpenJDK know, they are all lazy incompetents for using `E` in the `ArrayList` source code! http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java  /s